# Wine 1.5.5 SAI crashes in PlayOnLinux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, playonlinux

Ubuntu 18.04,
32-bit architecture

I was trying to install an app (Paint Tool Sai) through PlayOnLinux, but Wine crashes each time I try to run it.

Here's what the debugger writes:

```
Running wine-1.5.5-SAI sai.exe (Working directory : /home/alika/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/PaintToolSai/drive_c/PaintToolSAI)
Wine cannot find the FreeType font library.  To enable Wine to
use TrueType fonts please install a version of FreeType greater than
or equal to 2.0.5.
http://www.freetype.org
Wine cannot find the FreeType font library.  To enable Wine to
use TrueType fonts please install a version of FreeType greater than
or equal to 2.0.5.
http://www.freetype.org
0028:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
```

I can open Paint Tool Sai with Wine 2.18 staging, but unfortunately the Pen Pressure only works with Wine 1.5.5 SAI.

Is there any way to prevent Wine from crashing?

Thanks in advance